# MySQL timestamp to datetime conversion

Tags: mysql, date

I have a very big MySQL table (millions of rows) that gets new data very 20 minutes. I did a mistake at first and have a timestamp data, while what I really wanted was a datetime column. How can I either eidt the current table or migrate it to a new one, as fast as possible WHILE still being able to append new data to either the old or the new table ?

Comment: No option to take the database offline and run the query, say in the middle of the night?

Comment: not really because the table monitors events that do happen every 20 min :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That rather depends on what/who is using the database, and what control you have...

One approach might be to:

- create a new table (with desired data structure) (`CREATE TABLE...`)
- amend code/processes that are writing to the database, so that they write to both the old and the new tables (but continue to read from the old table)
- when *everything* is writing to both, copy the old data from the old table to new table (`INSERT ... SELECT ...`)
- amend code/processes that are reading from the database so that they read from the new table (but continue to write to both)
- when *everything* is reading from the new table, amend the code/processes to only write to the new table
- when *everything* is reading from and writing to the new table (alone), you can delete the old table. (`DROP TABLE...`)

You could also do something similar with by altering the existing tables (i.e. creating a new column), but if your data is updating every 20 mins, you may have a very large table, in which case the ALTER TABLE query could take a while to run - so I'd recommend migrating to a new table instead.

Comment: that is interesting but seems very complicated. I cannot stop writing to the table but I can stop reading, would it change the process ?

Comment: also, should I use a scripting language to port it or does SQL offer native tools ?

Comment: @Cystack - yes it's complicated - but I'm assuming you're trying to maintain functionality on a production database, whilst making your changes. Stopping reading might allow you to combine 4th/5th changes, but I'd still recommend doing them separately. All the changes to the database can be done in the database - suggested commands added.